# Correct terminology between UTF8 and UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, terminology

Which of the two is correct terminology?

Comment: I asked google :) "Results 1 - 10 of about 50,400,000 for UTF8. (0.13 seconds)" vs "Results 1 - 10 of about 140,000,000 for UTF-8"

Comment: @Ben Alpert: Why did you remove the utf8 tag? The question is about UTF-8 and UTF8.

Comment: that's exactly why I changed all the utf8 tags into utf-8 tags a few days ago ;)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That means nothing. Absolutely nothing.

Comment: The sad part is, given a language tag above, this could be an answerable question.

Comment: This is not opinion-based. According to IANA, only "UTF-8" is correct:
http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xml
Giving "UTF8" as charset can lead to serious problems:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24323842/2733244

Comment: @billthelizard I don't believe that this is opinion based. I believe that the question should clarify the context

Comment: @sdc 1. The question *doesn't* clarify the context. 2. Look at the accepted answer. It starts with "That depends on where you use it..." This is an opinion based question.

Comment: Thanks @BilltheLizard, I created a more specific question to avoid the confusion. [UTF-8 vs UTF8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36094939/utf-8-vs-utf8-in-xml-files)

Comment: I remember mysql's (ver 6+) java driver (as a bug?) allowed utf8 and threw exception on utf-8 (and required small case).

Comment: According to https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#names-and-labels UTF-8 is the canonical name, but utf8 is an alias.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That depends on where you use it...

The name of the encoding is `UTF-8`.

A dash is not valid to use everywhere, so for example in .NET framework the property of the `System.Text.Encoding` class that returns an instance of the `UTF8Encoding` class that handles the UTF-8 encoding is named `UTF8`.

Answer (score 31):

It's definitely UTF-8. UTF8 is only used commonly in places where a dash is not allowed (programming language indentifiers) or because people are too lazy.

Answer (score 19):

Following the RFC standard the answer is UTF-8

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629

Answer (score 7):

I believe according to the Unicode Consortium, it's UTF-8.

Answer (score 6):

Also [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (great and thorough explanation of UTF-8)