# what is the difference between utf8 and utf-8?

Tags: utf-8, convention

just wondering that what is the difference between `utf8` and `utf-8`? or they are just the same? as I have read in an answer here at SO saying use utf8 for PDO as utf-8 generate errors sometimes.

**EDITS**
where would utf-8 be invalid to use? (as answered in another similar question)

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809620/utf8-or-utf-8

Comment: No difference, just convention.  See [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809620/utf8-or-utf-8

Comment: `RFC` and `IANA` says `UTF-8` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between "utf8" and "utf-8"; they are simply two names for [UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), the most common Unicode encoding.