# Ajax call on IE 9 (success data - undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

When calling specific service with ajax call IE9 returns "undefined":

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL_PATH,
    type: "get",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Inspecting same code in Firefox, Chrome, IE10+, it works. I even tried adding:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
datatype: "json",
```

to ajax call properties, but no luck.

Strange thing is that when I call a local JSON file, everything is okay in IE9, but when  returning from local server url (information from database) that error occurs. Taking a look at response body, I got well formatted json string.

**UPDATE:**
Also added the error catching block:

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
    },
```

but no luck, it doesn't go inside the error block, it catches "success"

Comment: Try adding an error callback and see if the XMLHttpRequest is throwing any errors on you.  With the current amount of info, we would need something more to go on to help.

Comment: added update with your suggestion. Still no luck

Comment: The datatype variable should be spelled dataType (capital T), but I'll doubt that solves anything.

Comment: Tried `$.getJSON(URL_PATH, function(data){ console.log(data); })`? also, can you show us what the URL actually returns?

Comment: Try removing the `; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: Tried everything from above, nothing gives me a result. Actually, settings up dataType to "jsonp" goes into error catching block, but can't investigate why. Will try to play with this more tomorrow, and will post actual response from Firefox Firebug

Comment: Nothing seams to work, and Firebug returns a well formatted json response: `[Object { rels=[1], icon="qc-icon", requirements=232, more...}, Object { rels=[2], icon="qc-icon", requirements=5, more...}, Object { rels=[1], icon="tosca-icon", requirements=194, more...},` ...etc

Comment: Even more - I had a trouble with answer with header 'application/json; charset= utf-8' (space beetween '=' and 'utf-8')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a problem. The response header of my rest service was set to **charset=UTF8** and the IE couldn't recognize that while other browsers work with no problem, the correct spelling needs to be **UTF-8** with a dash :) a rookie mistake. Thanks everyone for suggestions. Closing this thread now.

Answer (score -1):

there are 3 ways to solve this issue,

First one add following lines,

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/1.0.0/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js'></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Second one,

solve it by using dataType='jsonp' at the place of dataType='json'