# What is the different between UTF-8 and UTF8 in Oracle SQL developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle21c

What is the different between `UTF-8` and `UTF8` in Oracle SQL developer?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809620/correct-terminology-between-utf8-and-utf-8. Read comments as well. This (https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/08/know-the-difference-between-utf8-and-utf-8/) is about Perl, but might be an interesting reading.

Comment: Should I use UTF-8 or UTF8 for word: "Xin chào các bạn trên toàn thế giới." ?

Comment: UTF-8 *should* be the one.

Comment: Oracle uses term `UTF8` for Character set [CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8). The Character set name for "proper" UTF-8 is `AL32UTF8`. However, I don't know if this also applies to Oracle SQL-Developer or only to Oracle Database.